# swprint equivalent - replacing wchar_t with char

Tags: c

Here is the example code:

```
wchar_t buf[1024];
if(path)
{
    //path type that's const wchar_t*
    swprintf(buf,1024,L"%S",path);
}
```

I need to replace wchar_t with char. It looks like I should use the following code:

```
char buf[1024];
if(path)
{
    //path type that's const char*
    sprintf(buf,"%S",path);
}
```

Is it correct ? Why `sprintf` doesn't have `size_t` len parameter ?

Comment: There are many, many different version of the `s*printf` functions: varying in type (`char` vs `wchar_t`), as well as safety. Naked `sprintf()` doesn't provide the length of the buffer, so can easily overflow, `snprintf()` does.

Comment: `%S` is undefined in Standard C, please clarify if you are asking about Standard C, or about some particular compiler

Comment: As others said, it's `snprintf` you want. Beware that if the string produced is longer than the buffer then it will not include the null terminator so do that yourself (it's easiest to do this unconditionally rather than checking if the format was maxed out). That's true of `swprintf` too so you were already anyway ... right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sprintf()` doesn't have a length argument because it's old. The newer `snprintf()` does include a length argument, and should pretty much always be preferred:

```
char buf[1024];
if(path)
{
    //path type that's const char*
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s", path);
}
```

---

On your use of a `%S` format - that's a non C language standard one used by some [Single UNIX Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification) editions to indicate the corresponding argument is a 0-terminated `const wchar_t *` string. The standard equivalent that should be used instead is `%ls`. Both are wrong in your second code block if the comment saying that `path` is a `const char *` string is correct. Turn on your compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` is a good starting point for `gcc` and `clang`) and it should complain about that.